# How do I prevent JavaScript with whitespace from breaking in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am using the html / code editor in WordPress to insert some JavaScript. For reasons which I completely not understand, this code does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function onSubmit() {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Hello innerHTML!";
}

</script>

<button onclick="onSubmit()">Say hello</button>

<p id="result">test</p>
```

Whereas this code works without problems:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onSubmit() {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Hello innerHTML!";
}
</script>

<button onclick="onSubmit()">Say hello</button>

<p id="result">test</p>
```

So the blank lines before and after the function call cause the problem (in the generated html code by wordpress, the script tags get enclosed within paragraph anchors). Obviously running both scripts separately within a browser goes without problems.

Any idea why these blank lines cause this problem? A little longer script would be illegible without some blank spaces, imho...

Comment: Look at the HTML source code of the *rendered page*. I've got a pretty good idea about what the problem is, but if I'm right then it will be blindingly obvious if you look at the code the browser is getting.

Comment: Any error messages on the console? My best guess would be some invisible characters and not just blank lines ...

Comment: My best guess would be the editor is adding extra symbols in between. Can you post the source code of the page?

Comment: sounds like [wpautop](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop)

Comment: @vidja: that was the clue, thanks! I installed a plugin to disable wpautop on a post-by-post basis and the problem is solved! Marked your comment for the moderators, as I cannot accept it as the correct answer - hope they can.

Answer (score 0):

You have to either

1) take all the whitespace and line returns out of the script so WordPress does not add `<p>` tags and then the Javascript will work, as you discovered, or

2) disable `autop` in the post editor for all posts/pages
(see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop ) so WP doesn't add paragraph breaks, or

3) do the following, which leaves `autop` enabled globally, but lets you disable it with  and  tags in individual posts and pages.

**Add the function below to functions.php and use the two tags**

`<!-- noformat on -->` and `<!-- noformat off -->`

**in your page/post editor, i.e.**

```
    text will be rendered *with* autop

    <!-- noformat on -->

    text will be rendered *without* autop

    <!-- noformat off -->

    text will be rendered *with* autop
```

Content outside of the two format tags will have autop enabled, as noted.

**Add to functions.php of the theme:**

```
// <!-- noformat on --> and <!-- noformat off --> functions

function newautop($text)
{
    $newtext = "";
    $pos = 0;

    $tags = array('<!-- noformat on -->', '<!-- noformat off -->');
    $status = 0;

    while (!(($newpos = strpos($text, $tags[$status], $pos)) === FALSE))
    {
        $sub = substr($text, $pos, $newpos-$pos);

        if ($status)
            $newtext .= $sub;
        else
            $newtext .= convert_chars(wptexturize(wpautop($sub)));      //Apply both functions (faster)

        $pos = $newpos+strlen($tags[$status]);

        $status = $status?0:1;
    }

    $sub = substr($text, $pos, strlen($text)-$pos);

    if ($status)
        $newtext .= $sub;
    else
        $newtext .= convert_chars(wptexturize(wpautop($sub)));      //Apply both functions (faster)

    //To remove the tags
    $newtext = str_replace($tags[0], "", $newtext);
    $newtext = str_replace($tags[1], "", $newtext);

    return $newtext;
}

function newtexturize($text)
{
    return $text;   
}

function new_convert_chars($text)
{
    return $text;   
}

remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
add_filter('the_content', 'newautop');

remove_filter('the_content', 'wptexturize');
add_filter('the_content', 'newtexturize');

remove_filter('the_content', 'convert_chars');
add_filter('the_content', 'new_convert_chars');
```